# Git --bare work tree folder empty

Tags: git, github, shared-hosting, git-remote

I've followed [link](http://danielstrunk.me/blog/2017/01/23/automatic-deployments-with-git-on-shared-hosting/) for automatic deployments with git on shared hosting. A end running
`git push production master` shows 100% complete status, but when i checked the work tree [desired folder]. The folder is completely empty. The upload is done but where did the file went ?? When i tyr `git push production master` again  it says `Everything is upto date` but where did the code-files went ? Does anyone know what is going on ?? For info I'm using Inmotion hosting reseller package.

Comment: A `--bare` repository *has no work-tree*. That's the whole point of such a repository, because one that *does* have a work-tree can have someone working on/in it, which makes it a poor target to receive pushes. The link you point to suggests using a post-receive hook to deploy to an auxiliary (not-part-of-the-Git-repo) tree. If you are using this technique, make sure you hook is actually running. (Also, the instructions at that link are wrong.)

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, Because it is meant to be that way.

Descriptive answer,

Difference between **git init** and **git init --bare**

**git init** - A repository created with this command is where you actually edit, add and remove code.

**git init --bare** - A repository created with this command is for *sharing*(not modifying) and is mostly created at a shared location. Several developers can push in this repository but nobody can edit directly(and this is the beauty of *--bare*). Developers will clone the shared bare code, modify locally in their working copies of the repository and then push back to the shared bare repository.